# Contador de array com while em JS

Tags: javascript, array, while

Preciso contar os elementos de um *array* usando o laço `while` e exibir num `alert()`, mas não está exibindo no *browser* o número da contagem. Usando `for` deu certo.

Deixo meu código abaixo:

```
var deuses = new Array();
  deuses = ['aegir', 'aud', 'balder'];

  var i = 0;

   while (i < deuses){
        alert(deuses.length);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Explique melhor porque precisa fazer isto, porque na verdade não precisa de laço algum.

Comment: Se quer só o tamanho do array não precisa de um loop, basta usar `alert(deuses.length);`

Comment: No exercício pede para eu fazer usando cada laço de repetição.

Comment: É estranho porque, para fazer o laço, você já precisa saber o tamanho: `(while i< deuses.lengh)`

Comment: Coloque o enunciado.

Comment: (37.b) Crie o seguinte array: var deuses = ['Aegir', 'Aud', 'Balder']
E exiba um a um com alert() - De preferencia para laços de repetição (for, forEach, while, do{}while)

Comment: (37.b) Crie o seguinte array: var deuses = ['Aegir', 'Aud', 'Balder']
E exiba um a um com alert() - De preferencia para laços de repetição (for, forEach, while, do{}while)

Comment: Nada nele indica para contar os elementos. Me parece ser um problema de interpretação de texto.

Comment: Eu acho que o exercício deve pedir pra iterar no array e ir contando.

Comment: Me parece que o exercício pede para exibir os elementos com um alert() usando o while

Comment: @BrunoSuarez A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O que deseja não é contar os itens, até porque é complicado contar algo sem saber quantos tem, e sabendo quantos tem não precisa contar.

Para contar algo que não se sabe quantos existem só se tiver um terminador claro, o que não é o caso de um *array* do JavaScript.

O enunciado pede para fazer umas das cosias mais simples com o *array* que é varrer todo ele com um laço. De fato não tem como fazer diferente. Pode até usar uma função que abstraia isso, mas na prática terá um laço dentro dele.

Veja na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) como funciona o `for - of` cuja função é justamente andar elemento por elemento e dar uma variável para você fazer o que quiser com ela durante a execução daquele passo. Esta forma é rápida e segura, além de muito simples.

O exercício não pede para fazer algo complexo.

```js
for (var item of ['aegir', 'aud', 'balder']) alert(item);
```

Se quiser fazer bem manual poderia ser assim:

```js
var deuses = ['aegir', 'aud', 'balder'];
var i = 0;
while (i < deuses.length) { //vai até o tamanho já conhecido
   alert(deuses[i]); //pega o elemento indexado pela variável de controle do laço
   i++; //incrementa a variável para o próximo passo
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/ScanArray.js).

Mas você corre riscos. Este é um caso que parece óbvio, mas vejo muita gente cometendo erros até em algo simples assim, principalmente indo além do tamanho.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Maniero.